# Node.js - mongoose model.save() isn't saving data to my collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

When registering, my user doesn't get saved to the database. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Schema + model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testusers', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let userSchema = new Schema({
  steamId: String,
  username: String,
  avatar: String,
  tradelink: String,
  balance: Number,
});


let userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Find and save:

```
userModel.findOne({ steamId: profile.id } , (err,user) => {
      if(!user) {
        let newUser = new userModel({steamId:profile._json.steamid, username: profile._json.personaname,avatar: profile._json.avatar, tradelink: '', balance:0});
        console.log(newUser);
        newUser.save((err,user) =>{
          console.log(err);
          console.log('created user');
          return done(err,user);
        }); 
      }
      else {
        console.log('user exists');  

        return done(err,user);
      }
    });
```

Collection data (empty after save): https://prnt.sc/rmlsc2

Console output:

```
PS C:****> node app.js
(node:26628) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
{
  _id: 5e7b78aae3903a680486cb13,
  steamId: '76561198126366365',
  username: 'BaeWolfy',
  avatar: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d3/d36a7d04988b8730a0a75516a7dbfa24ee1a45fc.jpg',
  tradelink: '',
  balance: 0
}
null
created user
```

Comment: Hey there, your code seems correct. I just can tell why that happens in general: when the connection to mongo is not done properly, but yours seems correct. Mongoose does not say anything on default model if the connect was not successful, and try to save the document anyway.

Comment: can you please try this `mongoose.connect('mongodb:mongodb://localhost/testusers', {useNewUrlParser: true});`

Comment: Console says it's connected but i'm pretty sure it was also connected before even without the added code since i had open connections to my atlas cluster. Still does not save as well with the added code.

Comment: Atlas Cluster??? you are connecting to localhost. Did I miss something?

Comment: Why don't you print all the documents in the end, just to be sure it is not a problem of the Atlas?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a stupid mistake on my part and am very sorry to waste your time i'm new to this and for some reason i thought that using the mongodb community compass and connecting to the cluster served as a localhost but it definetly does not after realising my mistake i entered the atlas cluster connection string and it's working now. Thanks for helping me realise and again sorry for the time waste

Comment: No problem, glad to help. It happens in the beginning to everyone! really glad things worked out after all!

Answer (score 0):

Made a stupid mistake in the connection string I used localhost instead of my atlas cluster connection string. It is working now.

Comment: Can you add the problem? the code you had to change?

Comment: i was using `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testusers', {useNewUrlParser: true});` but i needed the connectionstring to my atlas cluster: `mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-s4jtr.gcp.mongodb.net/testusers', {useNewUrlParser: true});` User and password are ofcourse placeholders since i did not want to share those..